# vectorized date creation (with timezone)

Tags: r, timezone, posix, posixct

```
x=c("2016-03-10 15:15:00", "2016-03-10 18:00:00", "2016-03-10 14:30:00")  
tz=c("Asia/Tokyo", "America/New_York", "America/New_York")
```

How can I create a vector of POSIXct dates (in a vectorized way)?

I tried (even though it is not exactly a proper vectorization)

```
mapply(as.POSIXct, x=x, tz=tz)
```

but the result is not satisfying.
Edit: actually `mapply(as.POSIXct, x=x, tz=tz, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)` returns the correct date output (it is the list to vector conversion that fails). I am still looking for a good way to either avoid `mapply`, or to directly create  dates in a vectorized way.

Comment: You can only have one timezone in a vector. Convert everything to `UTC/GMT` and store the timezone separately is probably an advisable method.

Comment: @thelatemail I am trying to convert everything to the same timezone! But it seems there is no way to do that in a vectorized manner. the best I found is `as.POSIXct(mapply(as.POSIXct, x=x, tz=tz, SIMPLIFY = TRUE), origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT")`

Comment: That's probably as good as you're going to do - it is vectorised. `as.POSIXct(mapply(as.POSIXct, x=x, tz=tz),origin="1970-01-01",tz="UTC")` will suffice, the `SIMPLIFY=TRUE` is default for `mapply`

Comment: Or if you wanted to get technical - `structure(mapply(as.POSIXct, x=x, tz=tz), class=c("POSIXct","POSIXt"), tzone="UTC")`